# Can you make numpy division by 0 give an Error not a Warning?

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy,

```
np.array([1])/0.0
```

gives:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
```

which is not a fatal Error. Is there any way to make division by zero give always give a fatal error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

```
numpy.seterr(divide='raise')
```

The [numpy.seterr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html#numpy.seterr) also allows you to define behaviour for overflow, underflow, invalid operations etc. The possible behaviours are error, warning, ignoring the problem, calling a handler function, or just logging the error

Comment: Awesomely awesome!